# How to make case insensitive comparison between a string value and input string

Tags: python, variables, input

I created an input() and I want user to enter specific values like `kg` or `KG` or `Kg` and make any other values `return` "invalid entry"

when I try to assign other values to the variable `unit1`, it is taking the last entry or it throws an error

That's my code:

```py
    weight=int(input("Enter weight: "))
    unit= input("Kg or Lbs: ")
    unit1= "kg"
    unit2="Lbs"
    if unit==unit1:
        print(weight/0.45)
    elif unit==unit2:
        print(weight*0.45)
    else:
        print("invalid entry")
```

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and ensure that your code appears here exactly as you have it. Please also read [ask] and make sure your question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the casing of the strings to the same. String comparisons are case sensitive, so the string `Lbs` is not same as `lbs`

`str.lower()` is your friend here :)

You should also check to make sure someone is entering an integer for your weight so your code doesn't crash. Try this!

```
while True:
    try:
        weight=int(input("Enter weight: "))
        break
    except:
        print("Invalid value entered for weight")
        
unit= input("Kg or Lbs: ")
unit1= "kg"
unit2="lbs"

if unit.lower()==unit1:
    print(weight/0.45)
elif unit.lower()==unit2:
    print(weight*0.45)
else:
    print("invalid entry")
```

You could also use `string.upper()` in case this suits you more